# Laravel Ajax Pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-4, pagination

I am trying to get pagination for ajax search filter based of of checkbox clicks. My controller function on each checkbox click :

```
public function ajaxGetServices(){

    $a_data = Input::all();

    Session::put('a_data',$a_data);
    $i=0;
    if(count($a_data) == 0){

        $temp = User::has('editor')->paginate(4);
        $this->data['editors'] = $temp->toArray();

        if(Auth::user()){
            $this->data['favorited_editors'] = Favorite::where('member_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->get()->toArray();
            $i=1;
        }


    }else{


        $editors = User::with(['editor.credentials','editor.specialties','editor.ratings']);
        $temp=$editors->whereHas('editor', function($q) use ($a_data){
            $q->whereHas('specialties',function($sq) use($a_data){
            $sq->whereIn('specialty',$a_data);
            });
        })->paginate(2);

        //var_dump($temp->toJson()); die();

        $this->data['editors'] = $temp->toArray();
        if(Auth::user()){
            $this->data['favorited_editors'] = Favorite::where('member_id','=',Auth::user()->id)->get()->toArray();
            $i=1;
        }

    }//endelse

    if($i==1){

        return Response::json(array('editors' => $this->data['editors'], 'favorited_editors' => $this->data['favorited_editors']));

    }
    else{
        $this->data['favorited_editors'] = array();
        return Response::json(array('editors' => $this->data['editors'], 'favorited_editors' => $this->data['favorited_editors']));
    }


}
```

this gives me total pages, current page, per page, from and to fields for pagination. now I am going to need to regenerate the links for pagination so as to reflect the above result.  please guide me about how can i go about doing it. Also, if needed I can supply more code to clarify my question. thanks in adv.

Comment: also, currently I am sending links() data along with other result. and in ajax success function I am replacing the paginated `ul` with "links" data. But every links has `getServices?page=2` but it throws ` MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this articles will be helpful 
http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/easy-ajax-pagination
https://gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902 (complete example so I didn't provide any explanation)